# How do I force YouTube to play videos in their lowest resolution?

Tags: youtube, configuration

Is there any good method that forces my web browser to play all YouTube videos on the lowest definition, even if the video offers a higher resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Log in to YouTube, [go to the playback settings](http://www.youtube.com/account?feature=mhum#playback/quality) and select that you have a Slow Connection.

Comment: This will use a lower resolution, but often not the lowest. e.g. 360p vs 240 or 144.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the parameter `fmt` to the URL. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube . Google can help you find Greasemonkey scripts that do that automatically.

Comment: This is better than what I posted! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs takes you right to the section to which he's referring.

Answer (score 1):

Add `&hd=0` to the YouTube URL. That will display the video in 360p.

Ex. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxdtVWvfFSU&hd=0

Additionally, you can add `&hd=1` instead of `&hd=0` to the URL to get 720p (if available).

E.g.: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxdtVWvfFSU&hd=1